# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.(appname). Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

Im trying to make an android app using Firebase. I believe I have done everything right to set it up, but I'm still getting this error message: "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.squadunite. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first."

I've been trying many solutions so my code might look a bit messy.

App-level build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    namespace 'com.example.squadunite'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.squadunite"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}
```

Activity using Firebase:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialButton registerButton;
    TextInputLayout usernameLayout;
    TextInputEditText usernameInput;
    TextInputLayout passwordLayout;
    TextInputEditText passwordInput;
    TextInputLayout repeatPasswordLayout;
    CheckBox termsCheckbox;
    Animation termsCheckboxAnimation;
    TextView loginLink;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public void initializeElements() {
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        usernameLayout = findViewById(R.id.usernameLayout);
        usernameInput = findViewById(R.id.usernameInput);
        passwordLayout = findViewById(R.id.passwordLayout);
        passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
        repeatPasswordLayout = findViewById(R.id.repeatPassword);
        termsCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.termsCheckbox);
        loginLink = findViewById(R.id.loginLink);
        termsCheckboxAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake_animation);

        // Initialize Firebase Database
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("users");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());

        // Remove toolbar
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        initializeElements();
        termsCheckbox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        // When username input is focused
        usernameInput.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) {
                usernameLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);
                usernameLayout.setHelperText("Pick a username between 3 and 16 characters long.");
            }
            if (!hasFocus) {
                usernameLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        // When password input is focused
        passwordInput.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) {
                passwordLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);
                passwordLayout.setHelperText(getString(R.string.passwordHelperText));
            }
            if (!hasFocus) {
                passwordLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        // When register button is clicked
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String username = usernameLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String password = passwordLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String repeatPassword = repeatPasswordLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();
            if (validateUsername(username)) {
                usernameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            if (validatePassword(password)) {
                passwordLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            if (validateRepeatPassword(repeatPassword, password)) {
                repeatPasswordLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            if (validateRegister(username, password, repeatPassword, termsCheckbox.isChecked())) {
                String userId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                databaseReference.child(userId).child("username").setValue(username);
                databaseReference.child(userId).child("password").setValue(password);
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });

        // When login link is clicked
        loginLink.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openLoginActivity();
        });
    }

    enum Error {
        USERNAME_MISSING,
        USERNAME_TOO_LONG,
        USERNAME_TOO_SHORT,
        USERNAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS,
        PASSWORD_MISSING,
        PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT,
        PASSWORDS_DONT_MATCH,
        PASSWORD_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS,
        REPEATPASSWORD_MISSING,
        TERMS_NOT_ACCEPTED
    }

    public void onError(Error error) {

        switch (error) {
            case USERNAME_MISSING:
                usernameLayout.setError("Choose a username.");
                break;
            case USERNAME_TOO_LONG:
                usernameLayout.setError("Username too long.");
                break;
            case USERNAME_TOO_SHORT:
                usernameLayout.setError("Username too short.");
                break;
            case USERNAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS:
                usernameLayout.setError("Username contains illegal characters.");
                break;
            case PASSWORD_MISSING:
                passwordLayout.setError("Choose a password.");
                break;
            case PASSWORD_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS:
                passwordLayout.setError("Password contains illegal characters.");
                break;
            case PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT:
                passwordLayout.setError("Password too short.");
                break;
            case PASSWORDS_DONT_MATCH:
                passwordLayout.setError(" ");
                passwordLayout.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.emptyError);
                repeatPasswordLayout.setError("Passwords don't match.");
                break;
            case REPEATPASSWORD_MISSING:
                repeatPasswordLayout.setError("Repeat your password.");
                break;
            case TERMS_NOT_ACCEPTED:
                termsCheckbox.startAnimation(termsCheckboxAnimation);
                Toast.makeText(this, "You have to agree with the Terms & Conditions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateUsername(String username) {
        if (username.length() < 1) {
            onError(Error.USERNAME_MISSING);
            return false;
        }
        if (username.length() < 4) {
            onError(Error.USERNAME_TOO_SHORT);
            return false;
        }
        if (username.length() > 16) {
            onError(Error.USERNAME_TOO_LONG);
            return false;
        }
        if (!username.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+")) {
            onError(Error.USERNAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword(String password) {
        if (password.length() < 1) {
            onError(Error.PASSWORD_MISSING);
            return false;
        }
        if (password.length() < 8) {
            onError(Error.PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT);
            return false;
        }
        if (!password.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\-!?@&]+")) {
            onError(Error.PASSWORD_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateRepeatPassword(String repeatPassword, String password) {
        if (repeatPassword.length() < 1) {
            onError(Error.REPEATPASSWORD_MISSING);
            return false;
        }
        if (!repeatPassword.equals(password)) {
            onError(Error.PASSWORDS_DONT_MATCH);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateTerms(boolean terms) {
        if (!terms) {
            onError(Error.TERMS_NOT_ACCEPTED);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean validateRegister(String username, String password, String repeatPassword, boolean terms) {
        return (validateUsername(username) && validatePassword(password) && validateRepeatPassword(repeatPassword, password) && validateTerms(terms));
    }

    public void openMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();
    }

    public void openLoginActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

}
```